# How to create frameset using XSLT and msxsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, frame

I'm trying to convert an XML file into various HTML files that will display a menu in the left frame and content in the right.  It doesn't seem to want to generate the HTML files I need inside the frames:

```
msxsl data.xml stylesheet.xsl -o output.html
```

The transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="frameset"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="menu_frame"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="content_frame"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="frameset">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Company</title>
        </head>
        <frameset cols="20%,80%">
            <frame name="menu" src="menu.html"/>
            <frame name="content" src="content.html"/>
        </frameset>
    </html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="book" mode="content_frame">
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>Content</title>
     </head>
     <body>
    <apply-templates select="chapter"/>
     </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book" mode="menu_frame">
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>Menu</title>
     </head>
     <body>
    <apply-templates select="chapter"/>
     </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your source data.xml. Also are you expecting to get all 3 html files from one run of transformation?

Comment: If you want to generate several files with one stylesheet you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor and `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: I now get "xsl:result-document" may not be used here

Comment: actually i figured it out.  You can't use msxsl because it does not support XSLT 2.0

Comment: Some XSL 1.0 implementations have extension functions which are similar to the 2.0 `xsl:result-document`, so it's worth checking the documentation for yours to see if such a workaround exists. Of course, that means writing a stylesheet that won't be directly portable to other processors. Another solution is to have a non-XSLT postprocessing stage which takes the single file produced by a stylesheet and breaks it up into several documents.